# How do I encourage my cockatiels to feed their babies when they will just only sit on them?

Tags: behavior, eating

My cockatiels are both pied and have tried once already to lay eggs and killed them all. Now, a new one is here and it is day 2. They stopped feeding him and hes been chirping for quite some time and I'm very concerned. What do I do to save the little guy?

Comment: did you consider hand-feeding the bird yourself? you might be able to find some formula at a petstore. Check these instructions and good luck :  https://www.cockatiel.com/handfeeding.html